# Suppose that p and q are twin primes. Show that if x^2≡p (mod q) is solvable then so is x^2≡q (mod p)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that p and q are twin primes. Show that if x^2≡p (mod q) is solvable then so is x^2≡q (mod p).

So basically my though process behind this question is that any twin primes can be written in the form p and p + 2. That is x^2 = p (mod p+2) and x^2 = p + 2 (mod p). Not sure where from here though

Comment: Hm.. What results do you know?

Comment: Try Euler's Criterion

Comment: By Euler’s Criterion we have, (p|q) ≡ q^((p-1)/2) ≡ (p+2)^((p-1)/2)  I seem to be getting stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well - it seems that the solution the problem calls for is a straightforward application of quadratic reciprocity.

Remember that for $p,q$ odd primes we have that

$$\left(\frac{p}{q}\right) = \left(\frac{q}{p}\right)(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}\frac{q-1}{2}}$$

From the twin prime assumption the exponent on the RHS is always even.

Comment: My law of Quadratic Reciprocity is; $$\left(\frac{p}{q}\right) \left(\frac{q}{p}\right) = (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}\frac{q-1}{2}}$$ How do I get to yours from there? Can you just simply "move" (q/p) to the other side

Comment: @JonathanMckibbin: they are equivalent. Just note that the RHS is always 1 (since one of $(p-1)/2)$ and $(q-1)/2$ has to be even). Now if one term on the LHS is 1, then consequently the other term as to be as well. It is a straightforward application of the theorem.

Answer (score 0):

There are many cases to consider. Maybe (i) $p\lt q$ or (ii) maybe $q\lt p$.

We examine **Case (i).** We are told that $(p/q)=1$. There are several possibilities to examine.

Maybe $p=8k+1$. Then $(q/p)=(2/p)=1$. So we didn't even have to check whether $(p/q)=1$. (It is.) Maybe $p=8k-1$. Then again $(q/p)=(2/p)=1$.

Maybe $p=8k+3$. Then $(p/q)=(-2/q)=(-1/q)(2/q)=(1)(-1)$, so we cannot have $(p/q)=1$.

Maybe $p=8k+5$. Then $(p/q)=(-1/q)(2/q)=-1$.

Thus the truth of the assertion has been verified when $p\lt q$. we leave it to you to see what happens when $q\lt p$.